# Why doesn't unordered_map use underlying_type<Key>::type for the hash functuion when is_enum<Key>::value is true?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

As noted at [Can't use enum class as unordered_map key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18837857/1078224), one can't use enum classes as keys for unordered_map without specializing std::hash. Why exactly is this necessary, or more specifically, why can't unordered_map automatically provide an appropriate hasher using underlying_type when the key is an enum?

Comment: Because the standard hasn't specified that yet...

Comment: @MarcGlisse :So it would be technically possible? Are you aware of any proposal that would add this to the standard?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be. There are several proposals about hashing, I don't remember if there was one specifically about enums, you can search on the wg21 or isocpp websites if you like.